# Creating a new model in ember with a zurb foundation range slider bound to an attribute

Tags: ember.js, slider, zurb-foundation, ember-cli, zurb-foundation-5

I am trying to use the range slider from the zurb foundation framework with Ember. I want a slider next to an input field, both of them showing the same value updating each other so a user would be able to enter either a number by hand or use the slider to set a score for a game played in the past.

My template looks like this:

```
{{input type="text" id="new-game-score" value=newGameScore}}
<div class="range-slider" data-slider={{newGameScore}} data-options="start: 0; end: 16;">
  <span class="range-slider-handle" tabindex="0" role="slider"></span>
  <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
</div>
```

And in the controller I'm calling `this.get('newGameScore');` to get the value for the creation of the model.

When I open the template I get a text-input that behaves like I expect. It allows to set the score for the creation of the model. The `data-slider`-attribute of the slider next to it gets updated correctly, but it doesn't change how the slider looks and I can't move the slider at all.
When I set `newGameScore` as a function returning a number in the controller both the slider and the input field start out with the set value and I can move the slider. Moving it does not change the value of the input field though, while entering a number in the text field adjusts the `data-slider`-value without any visible change on the slider. The number used for the creation of the new model is the one from the text input.

I'm using ember-cli and installed foundation with `ember install ember-cli-foundation-sass`.
I have

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  'ember-cli-foundation-sass': {
    'modernizr': true,
    'fastclick': true,
    'foundationJs': 'all'
  }
});
```

in my Brocfile and the corresponding view looks like this:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().foundation();
  }
});
```

The controller is an ArrayController with the template showing all the games with their scores. I would like to keep at that way if possible.

I started out using the zurb foundation documentation:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html

and found the following solution to a more complicated but closely related problem:
http://danahartweg.com/foundation-5-sliders-in-dropdowns-using-emberjs

but I couldn't figure out how to properly synchronise the slider with `newGameScore`. http://danahartweg.com/foundation-5-sliders-in-dropdowns-using-emberjs states at the beginning of the article that ember with a foundation-slider is easy to do. So I assume I don't have to write custom on-change-functions to solve my problem, but maybe someone more experienced with ember can find a solution from bottom part of the article, although it seemed to me that this is only needed for the combination of the dropdown and the slider.

Thanks for reading and for any idea about this.
regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I gave it another try after a good night's sleep.
I added:

```
$("#new-game-score").on('change', function(e) {
  var target_slider = $('.range-slider');
  var new_value = target_slider.attr('data-slider');
  target_slider.foundation('slider', 'set_value', new_value);
});
```

And now the slider updated visibly when I enter values in the text-field.

I added:

```
var slider = this.$('.range-slider');
  slider.on('mouseup.fndtn.slider touchend.fndtn.slider pointerup.fndtn.slider', function(e) {
  $(e.target.parentElement).find('input[type=text]').trigger('change');
});
```

and to the slider: `data-options="display_selector: #new-game-score` and now it worked both ways!
I'm still a bit at a loss of why this all works, but my problem seems to be fixed.

It only works when I explicitly set `newGameScore` in the controller though and all in all I have the feeling I didn't use Ember as intended.
Also this only seems to work when I carefully make sure I release the mouse button while on the slider. If I want to set it to max for example and release the mouse button outside of where the slider is, the text-field gets updated but `newGameScore` does not.

I made it work with:

```
this.$(".slider-input").on("blur", function(e) {
  var target_slider = $(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement).find(".range-slider")
  var new_value = target_slider.attr("data-slider");
  target_slider.foundation("slider", "set_value", new_value);
});

this.$(".range-slider").on("change.fndtn.slider", function(e) {
  $(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement).find("input[type=text]").trigger("change");
});
```

in the view.

I'm still unhappy with setting the initial value in the controller. I'm unsure about `on('blur')`, but `on('change')` lead to a infinite circle of both functions calling each other.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with an Ember app, but I do remember working with some of the quirks you've mentioned here.

In my article, I was data-binding both the slider value and the input value. Honestly, though, it would probably work better to just have the `data-slider` feed the input via the `display_selector` option without any binding. It's been a while since I worked with this code, so it might have been something I initially tried and failed with. It seems that might be better overall because it would let the `display_selector` option on the range-slider itself keep the internal state of the slider intact.

As far as using Ember data-bindings properly, html content is easy (as you've found), but element attributes are a little trickier. You have to use the `bind-attr` syntax: `{{bind-attr data-slider="newGameScore"}}`